# MongoDB Update or Push nested array в одном запросе

Tags: mongodb, запрос, mongodb-query

На американском stackoverflow нашел только 1 ответ из 2015 года, что такое в 1 запрос нельзя сделать, сейчас спустя 5 лет в mongodb появились много фич c итераторами $[], $, `$[<identifier>]`, и такое теперь сделать возможно?

Итак есть документ (id убрал)

```
{
  "userid" : "1",
  "events" : [
        {
          "cat" : 5,
          "count" : 0
        }
   ]
 }
```

Нужно: если у этого пользователя есть cat:5, то set:count, если объекта с cat:5 нету, то push. Возможно ли сделать это в 1 запрос?

Comment: Ребята , нашел что с версии 4.2 есть так называемые пайплайны. Вот пример из блога, я пока не смог адаптировать его под свою проблему : 
`db.exp.update({ _id:"x" }, [`
  {
    "$set": {
      "status": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": { "$gt": ["$total", 200] },
          "then": "Over Limit",
          "else": "Clear"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])